# Why is my POST method not being called? Code included

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, tomcat7

Fairly new to REST. Here are my two classes:

values.java

```
@Path("/values")
public class values {

int value = 0;
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int getSum() {
    return sum.sum(list);
}

@POST
public String addValue() {
    list.add(value);
    return "ok";  
}  

@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String deleteList() {
    list.clear();
    return "ok";
}

}
```

sum.java

```
@Path("/values/sum")
public class sum {

public static int sum(List<Integer> numbers) {
      int sum = 0;
      numbers.add(10);
    for(int i : numbers) {
          sum += i;
          }
    return sum;
}

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PACKAGENAME</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <!-- Register resources and providers under com.vogella.jersey.first package. -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>PACKAGENAME</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I access my Tomcat Server it just sends me 10 as a response (which is correct if POST isn't working). Any tips for a newbie? I try to pass http://localhost:8080/PACKAGENAME/api/values?value=15 and it just sends me back 10 every time. I think it is only using the GET method. How do I make it POST?

Thanks!

Update 1:

```
@POST
public String addValue(Integer value) {
    list.add(value);
    return "ok";  
}
```

Update 2: How would I go about passing value (?value=15) from POST to my list?

Comment: how you are passing the url? using REST client?

Comment: okay you need to use a REST client as mention by @wawek or create a form and make the action as post ... post request will not contain any data. The url which you are using is completely a get request.

Comment: Yup, I got it. I'm now receiving ok on my requests. For some reason, my get method only is giving me back a sum of 10 though...

Comment: You are only adding `value` into the list, and it was initialized with `int value = 0;` which is why your sum is constant over time

Comment: Isn't it only initialized with that value though? Would this be a good way of approaching it? See update 1 in OP.

Comment: Now I am receiving 415 error... Do I need to add @Produces under Post?

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

Answer (score 1):

When you pass http://localhost:8080/PACKAGENAME/api/values?value=15 then of course you call GET because you passed GET parameter with value in URL. If you want to call POST method then use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm) for example.

Comment: At first sight it looks fine. You have to test it by yourself.

Comment: Yup, I'm testing right now. I'm getting the "ok" response, but it doesn't seem like my list is being added to. When I call get, it only gives me 10 back.

Comment: Well for me you are testing it this way: you call POST trying to add something to list and then you call GET which creates new request and your list is created again so it does not know anything about earlier POST request.

Comment: How do I keep a variable stored after each GET? Do I need to connect a database?

Comment: It depends. You can store it in DB, file or some session bean if you use EJB.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. What is the best way of initializing my totalSum int and int value (to be added to list)? I currently just have them both set to 10 temporarily, but if GET is reinitialized each run, that wouldn't work. Aka: how do I adapt my code to database?